# Hiding and locking a column in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

We have performance appraisals in Excel format for all of our employees.  Employees use one column to rate themselves and their director uses another column to rate them.

The idea is to have the HR rep send the appraisal to the employee, the employee fills it in then returns it via email to the HR rep.  The HR rep will then hide the employee score column, lock it, password protect it, and email it to their director so they can be unbiased by the self-scores when rating their employee.  The director will then send the completed file back to the HR rep who will un-protect it and print it for the employee's file.

How do you password protect a document so that the column cannot be un-hidden?

Comment: Be aware that worksheet-level locking is easily overcome by code freely available on the web, so don't use this if there is any doubt about the veracity of the manager.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the menu bar and do `Tools->Protection->Protect Sheet`. From there, you can specify a password.

Comment: What is actually locked by this process can be modified, ensure that the option for 'Format columns' is disabled when locking the sheet.  It is by default, but previous selections for the sheet are 'remembered' by Excel.